# cURL Unknown SSL protocol error, unable to download pdf

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I am attempting to access a URL (pdf) using cURL. My code is below. The error I am receiving is **Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to my.domain.com:443**.

```
$url="https://my.domain.com/app/report?reportID=12345";
$agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, true);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo $output;
 } else {
    echo curl_error($ch);
 }

curl_close($ch);
```

If I add **curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);** I get an error from the site about not supporting that SSL version. Every other option (1-6) gives me the "Unknown SSL protocol error."

Unfortunately, I cannot share the URL. Is there any other option I can try?

Comment: Did you check if the site works with browser, `openssl s_client` etc?

Comment: The URL _does_ work when accessing it via a browser. I'm not familiar with openssl s_client, but just ran `openssl s_client -connect my.domain.com:443`. I am not sure what info to look for. It says Protocol: SSLv3, Cipher: RC4-SHA, gives me a Session-ID and Master-Key. The verify return code is 0 (ok).

Comment: RC4-SHA as the cipher is interesting. I don't know about the library but at least the command line version of curl disabled RC4 ciphers by default since they are insecure. You might try to explicitly enforce the use with `URLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST`. "Protocol: SSLv3" might also be a problem, because this should only be done if this is the best the server supports.  It might be that this is disabled too by curl for security reasons (SSLv3 is dead!).

Comment: For what it is worth, when viewing Page Info in Firefox, it says TLS 1.0, SHA-1 with RSA. Also, I noticed in Chrome's debugger, another difference is the host — my.domain.com when visiting in a browser — and adifferent.name.com when accessing via my php/cURL. Could that matter?

Comment: Also, hitting it with a browser shows two request cookies. I tried adding those with `CURLOPT_COOKIE` but that did not seem to make a difference.

Comment: Cookies have nothing to do with the issue because the get sent/received only after the HTTPS connection got established. As for the other name with the browser it might just be because of a redirect it got. There are lots of things which might cause problems here like the versions of curl you are using (to old, to new), SNI issues, version of openssl, thing on the server etc. Without having access to the server there is probably nothing one can do with remote analysis, so you are left to debug the issue alone. But http://noxxi.de/howto/ssl-debugging.html might help you.